# List iterator not incrementable assertion

Tags: visual-c++, game-development, listiterator, const-iterator

The DoCollision function is a callback function which is checking for collisions every frame by iterating over a collider list.

```
void Collision::DoCollisions(Game *game){
for (ColliderList::const_iterator colliderAIt = colliders_.begin();
    colliderAIt != colliders_.end();
    colliderAIt++)
{
    ColliderList::const_iterator colliderBIt = colliderAIt;
    for (++colliderBIt; colliderBIt != colliders_.end(); ++colliderBIt)
    {
        Collider *colliderA = *colliderAIt;
        Collider *colliderB = *colliderBIt;
        if (CollisionTest(colliderA, colliderB))
        {
            game->DoCollision(colliderA->entity, colliderB->entity);
        }
    }
}
```

if collision test passes for any two game entities, game entity(Base class for all game objects) class destructor invoke function DestroyCollider which removes the respective collider elements from the list.

```
void Collision::DestroyCollider(Collider *collider){
colliders_.remove_if(std::bind1st((std::equal_to<Collider *>()), collider));
delete collider }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the element of a list that the iterator points to. That invalidates the iterator, meaning you're not allowed to use it anymore.

A typical remove loop for a list or vector looks like this:

```
for (auto iterator = list.begin(); iterator != list.end(); ) {
  if (should_remove(iterator)) {
    iterator = list.erase(iterator);
  } else {
    ++iterator;
  }
}
```

Note how, if an element is to be removed, the iterator is *not* incremented, but instead replaced with the result of the `erase` call.

You will have to find a way to refactor your code to match this pattern. This is complicated because your condition is deep within the collision function, but you can do either that (which has the advantage of making your code more efficient by getting rid of the linear search, by the way), or you can, instead of immediately removing the elements, collect them in a separate list, and then remove them after you're done iterating over the main list.

Or you can turn `colliders_` into an intrusive list (e.g. from Boost.Intrusive, or hand-written). Intrusive lists are very good for situations like yours.

Comment: can i take an iterator variable as member variable of the class.
and assign it the new returned iterator from erase function.

Comment: one thing more...as you can see i am iterating over the list using double for loop. and if the collision test passes both the game entities destructor removes the collider. which means colliderA and colliderB both are being removed from the list. 
as a result, my both iterators can get invalidated at the same time.
how should i overcome that

Comment: That's two separate erase calls on two separate iterators. So you need to adjust both iterators. As to how to communicate those iterators, I don't know the greater design of your program. Personally I'd try to modify the collide function to return a "take this action" value, have "remove both objects" be one of the options, and thus pull the removing and iterator manipulation into the loop.

Comment: Thanks @sebastian for your suggetions.
Can i have list of shared_ptr instead of raw pointers. Will that solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is removing elements from the list while iterating. I'm not sure how having the elements be shared_ptrs would solve this.